# manipulate an HTML or CSS via PHP condition

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i have this navbar markup below, what is the easiest way to manipulate my `HTML` or `CSS`, that when the user is in `/contact.php` then my `<li> contact` would change to `<li class="active">Contact</li>`.

```
<ul>
<li class="active"> HOME </li>
<li> CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```

im not sure if my logic is correct. but this is what im thinking

```
if(isset($_GET) == '.../contact.php') { 
    // change Markup here
}
```

also, please be informed that im using wordpress. there might be some *wordpress ways* i might not be aware of ..

Answer (score 1):

I have found a link for you that might help, CMS systems like Wordpress of joomla work a little differently

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-active-class-to-active-menu-item

please let me know if there is anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know if you are using [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). If you do then you would not need to manually code the menu.

With regards to highlighting of current selected menu item and other features, I always refer to how twentythirteen theme handles it. See this [style.css from theme](http://s1.wp.com/_static/??/wp-content/mu-plugins/genericons/genericons.css,/wp-content/themes/pub/twentythirteen/style.css?m=1378908900j), search for "4.2 Navigation", with that code, you can have highlight on current menu item plus other features you may need in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress allready automatically adds current-menu-item on the menu item that is currently active, so your contact item in menu, when you are on the contact page allready has this class, provided that you are using wordpress native menu.

`.current-menu-item {// your code}`